# Having trouble returning class member

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, return, binary-search-tree

I'm making a **B** inary **S** earch **T** ree (BST for short) and I've run into a problem that I can't figure out.

I shall try and reduce the amount of code but it still may require quite a bit I'm afraid.

Nodes:

```
template <typename Type>
class BSTNode {          // Binary Search Tree nodes
    private:
        int key;        // we search by key, no matter what type of data we have
        Type data;
        BSTNode *left;
        BSTNode *right;

    public:

        BSTNode (int, Type); 
        bool add (int, Type);
        Type search (int);
        BSTNode<Type> *remove (int, BSTNode*);   
        BSTNode<Type> *minNode (int);                                                
};
```

Root:

```
template <typename Type>
class BST {                    // The binary search tree containing nodes
    private:
        BSTNode<Type> *root;   // Has reference to root node

    public:

        BST ();
        bool add (int, Type);
        Type search (int);
        bool remove (int);
```

};

I don't know how much code to give since I don't want to exaggerate, if you need more, say so please.

I do both do recursive search and remove

```
template<typename Type>
BSTNode<Type> *BSTNode<Type>::remove(int removeKey, BSTNode *parent) {

     // Here I try to remove nodes
     // Depending on the number of children a node has, I remove in different ways
     // The error occurs at removing a node with 2 children
     // here I look for smallest node greater than current node, replace current node, delete node I replaced WITH

    if (this->left != NULL && this->right != NULL){

        int *auxKey = &key;

        this = this->right->minNode(auxKey);  // replace

        return this->right->remove(this->key, this); // remove old node
    }
}
```

Here is minNode:

```
template<typename Type>
Type *BSTNode<Type>::minNode (int oldKey) {
    if (this->left == NULL) {
        //oldKey = this->key;
        return this->data;
    } else
        return left->minNode();
}
```

**This is where the error occurs:**

```
this = right->minNode(auxKey);
```

This causes a chain of errors, but I think the main error is:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
```

I'm guessing it's something simple I've overlooked, but I just can't find it, have been trying for quite some time.

**EDIT:** Decided for now to simply pass `key` to `minNode()` and ignore oldKey and auxKey, modified minNode to return pointer.

New Error, same place

```
lvalue required as left operand
```

Comment: It will help people if you condense your code snippets into one single file (you can copy and paste from headers), that gives the same error when you compile it. That way, (1) you'll get a line number in the error message that corresponds to the code you're showing, and (2) people can very easily take the code away and compile it on their favorite compiler, whose error messages they are most used to interpreting.

Comment: Mind you, it took templatetypedef less time to find the line with the error than it took me to write that advice. So in this case I'm wrong, it doesn't help!

Comment: So should I just give all the code ? I'm okay with that, but it's somewhat large. I was unsure of the etiquette for very large code "snippets".

Comment: in this case I wouldn't worry about it, assuming the answer you have fixes it. In general, you should try to construct a small, self-contained, correct example (http://sscce.org/), and ask a question about that. Basically, any code that's not needed to demonstrate the problem can be left out, but code that *is* needed to demonstrate the problem might be important to solve it. It's worse etiquette to post a small snippet that's missing something necessary to the problem, than to post a large snippet :-)

Comment: Your error says you declared `minNode( int )` and not `minNode( int* )`. Fix what you are passing in as an argument or change its declared parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Your minNode function takes in an int value representing the old key, but you're passing an int* into it in the remove function (specifically, auxKey).  Try passing in the value of the old key, not a pointer to it.  Alternatively, if you want to update the in parameter to hold the correct value (you seem to be trying to do this), change the parameter to a reference parameter.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm trying only to return the `data` but since data and key are separate, I want to modify key. Unless this code would not work, or it actually impairs functionality, I'm ok with living it as such